# How do I fix the "Type or namespace, or end-of-file expected"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PisteLaskuri : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text pisteTeksti;
    public float pisteMäärä ;
    public float pisteitäPerSekunti;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        pisteMäärä = 0;
        pisteitäPerSekunti = 1;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        pisteTeksti.text = pisteMäärä.ToString();
        pisteMääräInt += pisteitäPerSekuntiInt * Time.deltaTime;

        public int pisteMääräInt = Convert.ToInt32(pisteMäärä);
        public int pisteitäPerSekuntiInt = Convert.ToInt32(pisteitäPerSekunti);
    }
}
```

BTW Don't get confused by the variable names, they are in Finnish.
And this is quite badly coded thing... But it's probably fine!

Comment: When you get that error, it generally means you are missing a closing bracket somewhere.  But actually, I think your issue is from trying to declare a field as public inside a method. You can't do that.

Comment: you cannot create a `public` member within a method. I *assume* you want the last two lines **outside** of your `Update`-method

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain please upload your answer as an answer. that way the question can be closed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Update()
    {
        pisteTeksti.text = pisteMäärä.ToString();
        pisteMääräInt += pisteitäPerSekuntiInt * Time.deltaTime;

        int pisteMääräInt = Convert.ToInt32(pisteMäärä);
        int pisteitäPerSekuntiInt = Convert.ToInt32(pisteitäPerSekunti);
    }
```

This will fix your problem. Just put outside of the method your two int, you can't make them public in a method.

Comment: This will give you another error: _Cannot use variable `pisteMääräInt` before it is declared._